# Multiple rest api calls needed to render a page. How to make single api call like graphql - facebook? Any open source available like graphql?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Example
I am going to display Order Details
List of rest api

```
 Order List [{o_id:1,o_date:'',o_amt:100},...] 
   url/Orders

 Order Item [{i_id:1,i_quantity:10,i_unit_price:5,o_id:1},...]
   url/Orders/{Orderid}

 Item Description {i_id:1,i_description:'description'}
   url/Item/{Itemid}



----------------------------------
|           |  order              |
|orderlist  |   &                 |
|           |  item description   |
----------------------------------
```

Left side i select order I need two api calls for update my page. 
This is just for example like this i need to multiple api call.

Any opensource like graphql 
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sc8Pyc51uU)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try https://github.com/ericclemmons/react-resolver

In the readme it once claimed: when graphQL is out you should be able to make a smooth transiton.

They removed that but is still is a way to fetch async data on a component level.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on [Breeze.js](http://www.getbreezenow.com/). It requires proper implementation of [OData protocol](http://www.odata.org/) on the server side, but at the end you will be able to combine related calls into single one with similar query:

```
// Query for Order with ID 42,
// expanded to include related Item data.
// the result will contain both order and item data
var query = EntityQuery.from('Orders')
   .where('OrderId', 'eq', 42)
   .expand('Item');
```

Either way any solution with features similar to GraphQl will require following a protocol on client and the server, keep this in mind when you consider particular library/framework.